# Why global var is not incremented when using threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

For my code, pytest_status['finished'] variable is incrementing very interesting way. Sometimes i can see '2' or '3' (I expect corrent incrementing for every run_test function call):

```
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 2/53: success
test 1/53: success
test 1/53: success
```

and so on. I specially moved it out of lock, my code:

```
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock

pytest_status = {
    'finished' : 0,
    'total'    : 0
}

print_lock = Lock()

def run_test(test):
    status = subprocess.call(...)

    global pytest_status
    pytest_status['finished'] += 1

    print_lock.acquire()
    print 'test ' + str(pytest_status['finished']) + '/' + str(pytest_status['total']) + ': ' + ('success' if status == 0 else 'failure')    
    print_lock.release()

def main():
    params = [...]

    global pytest_status    
    pytest_status['total'] = len(params)

    print 'will perform ' + str(pytest_status['total']) + ' tests'

    pool = Pool(30)
    pool.map(run_test, params)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Aside from the thread/process issue, you'll want to lock access to the object while updating as well as printing it. (Both in case the `+= 1` is not atomic as well as to ensure the print statement has the correct value.)

Comment: @chepner but when i use lock.. processes, that are not able to acquire lock just skip locked part of code?!

Comment: That sounds ... wrong. A lock should cause the process to block until they can acquire the lock and execute the protected code. Otherwise, you have no idea which processes might have executed the code, or whether or not an individual process has executed a particular block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using threads. You're using processes. By definition, these have separate copies of all data. The only time you'd get 2 or 3 is when the same process happened to run more than one of the jobs.

Comment: Oh.. god. Is there a way to share variable between them somehow?

Comment: See the [multiprocesing docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) for examples of how to use `Value` or `Array` to do this.

Comment: Please also keep in mind this: If you have a global variable 'a' and use it inside a function, the latter one is just a copy of the global one. You have to write 'global a' once, if you really want to change the content of the global variable! This should not apply for your code, as pytest_status is a __reference__ to variables you change, not a variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pipe or Query if you want to transfer data between processes.

Comment: In fact yes, but i suppose it's overengineered solution there, in python should be standard solutions for this.

Comment: well Value and Array offerd by Daniel seems nice. Completly forget about it.